# How to calculate coordinates of center of image from an aerial camera whose FOV, attitude and position are given

Tags: image-processing, gis

I have a problem that involves a UAV flying with a camera mounted below it. Following information is provided:

- GPS Location of the UAV in Lat/Long
- GPS Height of the UAV in meters
- Attitude of the UAV i.e. roll, pitch, and yaw in degrees
- Field of View (FOV) of the camera in degrees
- Elevation of the camera w.r.t UAV in degrees
- Azimuth of camera w.r.t UAV in degrees

I have some some images taken from that camera during a flight and my task is to compute the locations (in Lat/Long) of 4 corners points and the center points of the image so that the image can be placed on the map at proper location.

I found a document while searching the internet that can be downloaded at the following link:

---

http://www.siaa.asn.au/get/2411853249.pdf

---

My maths background is very weak so I am not able to translate the document into a working solution.

Can somebody provide me a solution to my problem in the form of a simple algorithm or preferable in the form of code of some programming language?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, as a matter of principle I don't write code for other people (for free).  Why don't you make a start at solving it and post your questions once you get stuck?  It should be possible using mostly high school level trigonometry.

Answer (score -1):

As I see, it does not related to image-processing, because you need to determine coordinates of *center* of image (you even do not need FOV). You have to find intersection of camera principal ray and earth surface (if I've understood your task well). This is nothing more then basic matrix math.

See [wiki:Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

Comment: Since he needs "four corner points" and not just the center, knowing the FOV is actually required.